# How to keep contents inside a cell of a table with some margin

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following HTML code:

```
<table width="600px" height="275px" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="background: #ffff00; padding-left:0px; padding-right:0px; text-align: center;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">Silo'd Doc &amp; Header - &quot;Your doctors wants to connect with you.&quot;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="text-align: center;">        
                  <td style="height: 275px; width: 175px; background: url('http://wmed.com/images/email/POLCampaign/BlueBox.png') no-repeat;">STUFF GOES HERE</td>
                  <td style="height: 275px; width: 175px; background: url('http://wmed.com/images/email/POLCampaign/BlueBox.png') no-repeat;">OTHER STUFF GOEScd HERE</td>
                  <td style="height: 275px; width: 175px; background: url('http://wmed.com/images/email/POLCampaign/BlueBox.png') no-repeat;">AND FINALLY</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Displays the following in IE:

And the following in FF:

I would use `SPAN`/`DIV` but only `table` is allowed in my codebase.

How can I have it so the blue boxes are centered horizontally within the yellow main table and each blue boxes contents stays inside the blue boxes with a 5px padding at the edge in all the browser?

Comment: What's wrong with that? http://jsbin.com/furapotu/1/edit

Comment: @HashemQolami That is what I am looking for except the `TD` I don't want it to expand, just make the text keep going to the next line. Any idea? Also, a little padding inside the blue so the text doesn't go to the edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `overflow:auto` and `word-wrap:break-word` to your `<td>` elements.

CMIIW~

Comment: Not working :/ The image just keep stretching which I don't want.

Comment: I added your code along with other codes and it's working. Thanks.